# Android Studio - reading and writing files

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
private void writeToFile(String filename,ArrayList<String>arr)throws FileNotFoundException{
    try{
        FileWriter writer= new FileWriter(filename);
        String str="";
        for(String string:arr){
                  str+=string;
                  }

    }
    catch(IOException e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My problem is I keep getting `fileNotFoundException` errors.

Is this the right way for android studio?

Comment: You are probably trying to write in the wrong directory. Something like Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + " \filename.txt"

Answer (score 0):

You were probably looking for [this training](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) (Saving Files | Android Developers).

Sample code inside.